# html2fpdf using php jquery and ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following jQuery which makes a request to a php file called html2fpdfconverter.php:

```
 $("#exportentry").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     if(submitted){
       //export
       var data = $("#container").html();
       var filename = "Entry Report.pdf";
       var dateString = $("#datepicker").datepicker().val();
       $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
                 url: "html2pdfconverter.php",
         data: {data:data, filename:filename, date:dateString},
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(data) {                
               //get min max dates assigned            
         alert('success');             
         }         
       })
     }else{
       alert("No Report To Export");
     }
     });
```

**html2fpdpf.php**

```
<?php

require('html2fpdf.php');

if(isset($_POST['data'])){
  $urlcontents = $_POST['data'];
  $filename = $_POST['filename'];
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  convert($urlcontents, $filename, $date);
}

function convert($contents, $name, $currdate){ 
  $pdf=new HTML2FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
  $pdf->Cell(40,10, "Entry Report");
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
  $pdf->Cell(90,12,'-   '. $currdate);
  $contents = strip_tags($contents, '<html><body><meta><img><h2><h4><br><div><ul><li><span>');
  $pdf->SetY(20);
  $pdf->WriteHTML($contents );
  $content = $pdf->Output('', true);
  $file = fopen($filename, "w");
  fwrite($file, $content);
  fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Using firebug I can see that the data is posted correctly to the php file. However, nothing happens...no pdf is created and no download dialog is displayed despite firebug saying the php request is OK.

I get the following response in firebug:

> %PDF-1.3
>       3 0 obj
>       <>
>       endobj
>       4 0 obj
>       <>
>       stream
>
> x�͘�r�0��}��b�"BK��qI�e��EX�X��.��Ax_�s��3.b`�I-��s����óJd�NN����0���I��l5ā�n������DH����L28��.൹����O8^m����E��28IĒ1�NQ=bz��w(�Gl�Ѯ��Z�$BA,8��r���߾�i��=9�-HJ¨��l��8Ve�o&�];xw�y����_��\Ey�8!��T�e���ܵ�   �T���j:�F���UE�X8/3�}�̨�>�~5T�$
>
> ������0��>?�Q:!qH�ۨ�����D��XEC��`���Ԥ�����͇���hI�cA��l�����ηy�/�՟���rP.���V�
>   T/�u��|���9����U9t�'|IJ��.�c�28+�<ÃX�����U�|�;k�AI�"�[�ȑ��"�6���vYs�����b�)�H퓀�Ph�,���P:T��x�1,,��Ey�b"Mh(��`�ti��.C4D�(�`��5�Eա,ۃ��^���*4QܧAݑ,!*ص�`/�Ml�/�z\;$C����x�dPId��ƃ]4�0pYYS���  �B<�    Q�Z�#�=�[��A^�,]��
>   �k��d/�h�j�V���H�n4ʖ
>       endstream
>       endobj
>       1 0 obj

There's a whole load more..I'm not sure why this isn't working...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this.
The solution to this problem involves two things:

1. The html that will be converted to PDF is poorly constructed and should review it.
2. If the HTML is this good, then the problem is in the php.ini, in my case I used XAMPP for Windows.
   in c:/xampp/php/php.ini, `variable register_long_array = Off`
   change it to `variable register_long_array = On`

Then it shows you the PDF both IE, Mozilla, Chrome. I have not tried on safari.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you output the content to the browser, instead of a file.

Try this :

```
$content = $pdf->Output('', true);

$file = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($file, $content);
fclose($file);
```

**EDIT:**

When you're sure that the file is created, you have to handle the opening of the newly created pdf with jQuery. One way to do it is to create an iframe which is updated each time you export a pdf.

```
frame = document.getElementById('exportFrame');
frame.innerHTML = "<iframe src='/path/to/file/File.pdf' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' height='0' width='0'></iframe>";
```

And add this to your html markup :

```
<div id='exportFrame'>&nbsp;</div>
```

See Documentation : http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:output
It's a basic code, remember to check the filename for security reasons (never trust user input...).

Comment: This is not the issue. I have had this working with another example..My intention is to make the user download the file. The documentation says this is the way to do it...

Comment: This is the issue.
The documentation says this is the way to do it IF you're using a direct link to your page. But here, you're making an Ajax request, and you can't force download this way.
You have to write the content to a file, and then print the filename in the responseText. Then, you have to open the file with jquery (for example, creating a hidden iframe which you update after request with the url of your newly created file).

Comment: ok..so I added your code at the end of my hp file and nothing happens still..see my edited code

Comment: The file is created ?
Now, you have to write the jQuery code which will handle the update of an iframe.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand..I'm not using iframes..Why do I have to update an iframe?..No file is created on my server either.

Comment: You're using an Ajax Request, and with ajax you can't force download. So the solution i give you, is to write the pdf content to a file, and then if you want to download the file without reloading the user's page, you'll have to use a trick. The trick is to use a hidden iframe, which you update with the url of the file, this will force the download ! See my edited post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3141/discussion-between-imad-moqaddem-and-user906568)

Answer (score 0):

In order to open the browsers download dialog, you have to point the browser directly (or iframe) to the file url, it is not possible to
open a download dialog to download data stored in a js variable.

If you want to directly download the file (without saving it on disk first) using `$pdf->Output($name, "D")`, you could do your POST request by creating a `<form>` and use input fields to send `data`,`filename` and `dateString`, then if you submit the form, the download should start.